# Integrate a Rails application into a site made in wordpress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress

I am currently building an application (An Analyzer tool) in Rails 3.2. I am just about done with it in the development phase. I am having our designer begin work on designing our new website where this application will be integrated.

I had an idea though and wanted to get a feedback badly.

What if the website is  built on WordPress, but that that analyzer tool (Which is built in rails) , which has its own backend/reporting system and that element of the site accounted for the custom coding? So it was a hybrid of Wordpress and this analyzer tool? 
Is this possible? And if it's possible do you foresee any challenges with that?

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out this plugin for wordpress:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rails-integration-api/

It basically copies any 3rd party app (such as Wordpress) to a subdirectory of your Rails app.

The real challenges are in the details.... authentication, authorization between admins in the WP site and the Rails app, etc.  A question you should ask yourself is how much are the website(wp) and Rails app going to need to talk to each other, if at all?

However, if the WP site is just used mostly as an informational site or maybe a blog, you can place your WP site inside the /public directory of your rails app, tweak the config files (if you're running Apache/Passenger etc), and go from there.

Comment: Thanks @ply, I had a glance at the plugin's documentation before some time too...But on its site there's a note that
This plugin hasn't been updated in over 2 years. It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress.
So i was just a bit scared to use that.Is there any other option.Or have you used that plugin yourself so that i may be assured if its working perfectly fine.
Thanks

Comment: Good point, I haven't used the plugin I guess the bigger question is, is Wordpress simply used as a platform to serve the website (and maybe a blog) for the analyzer tool?  Also, what kind of server will you be running the rails app on?

Comment: Thanks again.Yeah Wordpress here is simply used as a platform to serve the website (and also for the blog) for the analyzer tool.The rails app is hosted on heroku and we are using the thin server.

Comment: @JimmyThakkar Did you figure out how to put a wp blog in a rails site on heroku? What did you end up doing?

Comment: @bonhoffer No i didnt figure out a solution for putting a wp blog in my rails site, i used refinery-CMS Blog instead. Please checkout https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-blog if you wanna do the same.